# Export PHP with Google charts and table as PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, charts, google-visualization, dompdf

I have a PHP page with Google charts and a table below it that needs to be exported as PDF.

I tried using

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
        doc.addImage(chart.getImageURI(), 0,0);
        doc.save('chart.pdf');
```

for the google chart and dompdf for the table but obviously when using both code at once it doesn't work.

Is there a  way to export the page as a whole, or a PDF page of the chart and 2nd for the table all within the same PDF file?
[image]

Comment: And why do you add the table with dompdf and not jspdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to get an image of the entire page,
then send that to pdf...

just need to make sure both the chart and table have finished drawing.

see following working snippet...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'table']
  }).then(function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['x', 'y0', 'y1'],
      ['0-10', -3, 3],
      ['11-20', -2.5, 2.5],
      ['21-30', -2, 2],
      ['31-40', -1.5, 1.5],
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    var chartReady = false;
    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
    var tableReady = false;


    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', onChartReady);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', onTableReady);

    chart.draw(data, {
      hAxis: {
        format: '#,##0.000',
        ticks: [
          {v: -8, f: '8.000'},
          {v: -6, f: '6.000'},
          {v: -4, f: '4.000'},
          {v: -2, f: '2.000'},
          0, 2, 4, 6, 8
        ]
      },
      isStacked: true
    });
    table.draw(data);

    function onChartReady() {
      chartReady = true;
      onIsReady();
    }

    function onTableReady() {
      tableReady = true;
      onIsReady();
    }

    function onIsReady() {
      if ((chartReady) && (tableReady)) {        html2canvas($('#dashboard_div').get(0)).then(function(canvas) {
          // export pdf
          var pdfDoc = new jsPDF({
            orientation: 'landscape',
            unit: 'px',
            format: [canvas.width, canvas.height]
          });
          pdfDoc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 0, 0);
          pdfDoc.save('page.pdf');
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.table {
  text-align: center;
}

#table_div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/html2canvas@1.0.0-rc.5/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jspdf@1.5.3/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div class="table">
    <div id="table_div"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hope this helps. note: the above snippet appears to block the download on save...

Comment: Thanks for the help, when i save the pdf it only shows the table but not the chart

Comment: will you update the question with the code? I moved the above snippet to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efrsj5hz/), where you can see both are saved...

Comment: Found out the problem, was missing some line. Thanks!